# Build user-specific izpack installer during server runtime

Tags: java, installation, izpack

I am looking for a freeware OS independent installer.

Users can configure the application from web interface and then download it. Server should build the installer with default files and include user configured files. All files are stored in a database.

Does anybody know if it is possible to build the installer during server runtime with user-specific configuration files with izpack, And what would be the sequence of the events?

eg. load all files (incl user configuration) from database, write files to file system, modify izpack installation file to contain the resources, execute command to build the installer, load the installer from file system, serve it to user, remove files.

Thanks,
ozooner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is yes, we do something similar for our build system

The long answer would be, work out the normal workflow you would need in order to build the package manually and automate it

Off the top of my head...

1. Layt out the files in the required structure
2. Update the izPack script to meet the requirements of the Custer
3. Run izPack to build the package